# Lambda calculus - why isn't it possible to make another beta reduction here?

Tags: lambda-calculus

I have been told that the term

```
(z (λy.z x) (λy.y z))
```

is already in it's normal form - but I don't understand why. Couldn't one make another beta-reduction in this state and replace all occurences of `y` in the term `(λy.z x)` by `(λy.y z)`, so that it would evaluate to:

```
(z (λy.z x) (λy.y z)) ==> (z z x)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Application is generally taken to be left-associative. That is,

```
z (λy.z x) (λy.y z)
```

is not

```
z ((λy.z x) (λy.y z))
```

It is

```
(z (λy.z x)) (λy.y z)
```

which would require the value of `z` to beta-reduce.